# Unable to start Griddb node on CentOS 7

Tags: griddb

After installing Griddb, I was unable to start the node, I ran this code on my centOS 7 virtual box:

```
sudo su gsadm 
gs_startnode -u admin/admin
```

This returns an error message:
ADO103: Unable to start node, confirm event logs (gridstore-YYYYMMDD-n.log, gsstartup.log)

please, how can I solve this?